# Navigator.pop(context) show black screen while finish the last Activity in stack in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigator, onbackpressed

I have searched a lot about this, but didn't find the correct solution yet. I want to know that what is equivalent to **finish() (in java for Android)** for Flutter

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: ()  {
    if (counter == 1) {
    // **What should I write here so that my current activity is destroyed with showing the Toast message.**
    }
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: "Press again for exit!",
      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
      gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
    );
    counter++;
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      counter = 0;
    });
    print(counter);
  },
 child: new Scaffold(
      ....................
           );
   );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "finish"? Are you referring to a method in another programming language, like 'onDestroy' in java for android?

Comment: @F-1 Yes, I am referring method in java for android. But in dart I didn't find this type method.

Comment: ok, here is some information https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html Sounds like you just need to pop the view when your counter reaches 1 which will cause the dispose method to be called. One thing you haven't explained is where the user is being sent after the dispose has occurred. It might be black screen because of an issue with the code associated with the previous view. Please post the full error log. I'll delete or edit my answer once you've explained more.

Comment: thanks @F-1, But I have found another way to do this. Please check my answer.

Comment: Cool. You should mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for this. Definitely it works!

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () {
      if (counter == 1) {
        return Future.value(true);
      }
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "Press again for exit!",
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
      );
      counter++;
      Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
        counter = 0;
      });
      return Future.value(false);
    },
    child: new Scaffold(
      ..................

    ));
 }
```